# Run firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping task from app/build.gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Is there any way to run gradle task from app/build.gradle file, so that when I build release APK task "firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping" will run automatically.

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Comment: no, i have not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dependsOn` for example (your `app/build.gradle`):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'

android {

}

dependencies {

}


task release

task archiveRelease(type: Copy) {
    from './build/outputs/apk', './build/outputs/'
    into "../releases/${rootProject.ext.configuration.version_code}"
    include('app-release.apk', 'mapping/release/mapping.txt')
    rename('app-release.apk', "${rootProject.ext.configuration.package}_${rootProject.ext.configuration.version_name}_${rootProject.ext.configuration.version_code}.apk")
}

project.afterEvaluate {

    dependencyUpdates.dependsOn clean
    assembleRelease.dependsOn clean

    def publishApkRelease = project.tasks.getByName("publishApkRelease")
    publishApkRelease.dependsOn assembleRelease

    release.dependsOn publishApkRelease, firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping, archiveRelease
}
```

I created a new task called `release`. It depends on `publishApkRelease` (comes from [gradle-play-publisher](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher)), `firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping` and `archiveRelease`. And `publishApkRelease` depends on `assembleRelease`.

At the ned you just call `./gradlew release` and it will build your release version, uploads the apk to Google play, the mapping file to Firebase and archive a copy of the apk and mapping file.